# Compton wavelength in massive vector field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

What is the significance of Compton wavelength in massive QEDs? When we expand $A_{\mu}$ in Fourier modes, is there any significance for modes whose wavelength is less than Compton wavelength?

Comment: Common wavelength is the typical length scale which separates the high-energy relativistic regime from the low-energy regime that can be described by ordinary Schroedinger equation or its higher-spin modifications.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus for a vector field, is it true that the field drops rapidly after compton wavelength distance ?

Comment: I don’t think so, but the propagator does drop rapidly.